# How to programmatically create an SSIS Package?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, dataflowtask

I am trying to **programmatically** create an SSIS package containing a simple data flow from table A to table B in the same database. I am using the example given [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136020.aspx).
The package gets created and saved to a dtsx file, but when I open it in visual studio I see that the source and destination tables have not been selected.

I also want to insert a transformation task in between before it reaches the destination.

---

### EDIT

Well I have managed to get the source and destination tables selected and the task even ran successfully. Turns out I needed to

(a) use one oleDB connection each for the source and destination [I don't like this way; I want to use one connection only]

(b) set the Accessmode to 3 in the destination ***SetComponentProperty("AccessMode", 3)*** which equates to Table or View - fast load.

Is there some documentation on this somewhere. All I can find is what **SetComponentProperty** does, and not what all parameters it can take to do that. eg. what else can I put there besides "AccessMode"?, what does the second parameter 3 or 2 or 1 stand for?

Still trying to map the monikers. STOCK:PipelineTask means DataFlow Task. What is the moniker for say... copy column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is one of my frustrations with SSIS: that they do not provide simple table or map of the new terminology.

You can use a small piece of code to discover components available for use.

The code is located here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136106.aspx

When I ran it, I found the moniker for copy column to be:
Name: Copy Column
 CreationName: DTSTransform.CopyMap.1

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use the DTS .net assemblies you can use EzApi which provides a simpler syntax to create SSIS package programmatically.

> EzAPI is a .NET library written in C# by Evgeny Koblov one of the testers on the SSIS team to abstracts away a lot of the cumbersome low-level coding needed to create SSIS packages XML directly in a programming language

EzApi was first published as a part of the SSIS community samples project created by Microsoft product team:

- [SQLSrvIntegrationSrv](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=sqlsrvintegrationsrv)
- [GitHub - MSSQL SSIS community samples](https://github.com/fan130/mssql-ssis-community-samples)

And later it is published as a separate project to add support SQL Server 2016:

- [GitHub - EzApi2016](https://github.com/fpvmorais/EzApi2016)
- [NuGet Gallery - EzApi](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EzAPI/)

To get starteed with EzApi there are many link on the internet that you can refer to such as:

- [EzAPI – Alternative package creation API](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mattm/2008/12/30/ezapi-alternative-package-creation-api/)
- [EzAPI Overview](http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2012/01/ezapi-overview.html)
- [EzApi a C# library for creating SSIS packages programatically](https://www.kapacity.dk/ezapi-a-c-library-for-creating-ssis-packages-programatically/?lang=en)
- [Getting Started with EzAPI](https://www.dimodelo.com/blog/2013/getting-started-with-ezapi/)

Answer (score 0):

I used to have a copy of [SQL Server 2005 Integration Services](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-SQL-Server-2005-Integration-Services.productCd-0764584359.html), a Wrox book.  I am pretty sure it has a whole chapter or two dedicated to programmatically working with SSIS packages.  You may want to check out a local book store and flip through it, it may have what you want.

Sorry I can't give you anything more specific than a book reference.  Good luck.

Comment: I would also look at Kirk Haselden's SSIS book - it is more programmer-oriented.