# SSIS How to Map Hundreds of Derived Columns

Tags: sql-server, unicode, ssis, etl, derived-column

I have a table that needs to map 104 columns and convert from Unicode to non-Unicode, etc as `(DT_STR,10,1252)[ColumnName]` within the derived column editor in SSIS.

I cannot simply CAST from the SQL statement given I am ingesting from CDC Control task in SSIS and you have no opportunity to CAST outside of the derived column task.

Given I have over 100 columns to manually map, is there a way to dynamically do this in SSIS instead of going through each and every column manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to do that from Visual studio, but you [can automate the package creation process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221428/how-to-programmatically-create-an-ssis-package/55504230#55504230) using one of the following approaches:

*1) Business Intelligence Markup Language:*

- [BIML](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3094/introduction-to-business-intelligence-markup-language-biml-for-ssis/)

*2) Using C# / VB.net DTS Wrapper classes*

- [.Net DTS Wrapper Classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/building-packages-programmatically/building-packages-programmatically?view=sql-server-2017)

*3) C# EzApi library*

- [EzApi library](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mattm/2008/12/30/ezapi-alternative-package-creation-api/)

---

### Similar posts:

- [How to manage SSIS script component output columns and its properties programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55029854/how-to-manage-ssis-script-component-output-columns-and-its-properties-programmat/55031970#55031970)
- [How to Map Input and Output Columns dynamically in SSIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54781017/how-to-map-input-and-output-columns-dynamically-in-ssis/54797147#54797147)